# Pointer arithmetics. core dumped

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, g++

This is my small code. It works fine until dim=3. If I enter dim=4 I get this strange error:

makefile:10: recipe for target 'exec' failed
make: *** [exec] Aborted (core dumped)

I think "core dumped" appears when I try to access memory which I do not own but I cant see where the mistake is in this code.

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 
  3 using namespace std;
  4 
  5 int main(){
  6         int dim = 0;
  7         double* y = new double[dim+1];
  8         double* x = new double[dim+1];
  9 
 10         do{
 11                 cout << "Enter a dimension:\n";
 12                 cin >> dim;
 13                 if(dim<=0) cerr << "Error: Dimension is lower equal 0!\n";
 14         }while(dim<=0);
 15 
 16         for(int i = 0; i<dim; i++){
 17                 *(y+i) = dim*i + 7;
 18                 *(x+i) = dim*i + 1;
 19                 cout << "*(y+" << i << "): " << *(y+i) << "\t" << "*(x+" << i << "): " << *(x+i) << endl;
 20         }
 21 
 22         
 23         
 24         delete[] y;
 25         delete[] x;
 26         return 0;
 27 }
```

Comment: Go through that code line by line and explain what it does to your rubber duck.

Comment: Changing the value of `dim` doesn't magically change the allocations for `x` and `y`. You should probably read the value first, and allocate space later.

Comment: In the future please avoid having line numbers in code you show. If anyone wants to copy-paste the code and try it out it's a lot of work to remove the line numbers. If you want to mark out a specific line somehow, then use a comment on that line.

Comment: Your input loop breaks if they enter words, you should test `cin` instead of `dim<=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain what is wrong with your code:

```
int dim = 0;
double* y = new double[dim+1];
double* x = new double[dim+1];
```

`x` and `y` point to a single element because `new double[0 + 1]`

Then you ask the user to enter the dimensions. Once the user enters the dimensions your code breaks because you are trying to dereference a pointer that points to an invalid location. This is called `undefined behavior`. 
To fix this issue you have to first ask the user to enter the `dim` value and then allocate the appropriate space.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that in absence of loops of selection statements, C++ is a strict top-down language. It starts with the statements on top, and goes down to the last statement.

That means your allocations will use the original value of `dim` which is zero, so you only allocate a single element for each array. Modifying `dim` later will not cause the arrays to be reallocated. If you write more than one element into the arrays, you will go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*.

To solve this you need to move the allocation of the arrays to after you read `dim` from the user.

Comment: `Go through that code line by line and explain what it does to your rubber duck` thumbs up !